# How GPS device in car send notification to Android app when the car over the speed limit?

Tags: android, gps

For personal project, I would like to know How can I make small GPS device installed in my car to send a messages or "notifications" when the car get over the speed limit to android app which installed in any android mobile device? The message should be tell about the speed, time, and the location of the car.

All the maps and hardware staff is available. I am wondering about How  to make GPS device capable to communicate with Android app in my mobile phone? How it send the messages? How to store the maps to android thing??

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question depends entirely on the particular GPS unit in your car and it's capabilities of sending notifications on demand. It's not answerable here in it's current form, and is probably too localized to be of use to other people.

Comment: well what brand/model is your gps? There are many ways to send 'messages' to a networked android device. The likely holdup will be the gps device in your car. Why not use the GPS device on your phone itself?

Comment: This is probably to broad of a question. But your app will need two main "sections". One that is able to find the speed limit given the location of the vehicle. The other will set a listener to get a callback from the the device whenever the gps reports that the speed is higher than the limit in the current location. Just a fair warning, what you are aiming to do would likely be a massive project. If you are aiming to do something like this by yourself, you may be in for more work than you had imagined. EDIT: I thought you were wanting to use the gps on the device, if not then ignore this

Answer (score 4):

Your gps device send data (lat,long,speed,direction...) contumaciously after some intervals to global database and android apps get this information from database within a seconds.